# How I do optimize a slow query caused by a large dataset?

Tags: php, sql, optimization

I have pull back a lot of information and as a result, my page is loading in about 22~24 seconds. Is there anything I can do to optimize my code?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$result_rules = $db->query("SELECT source_id, destination_id FROM dbo.rules");

while($row_rules = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_rules)){
$result_destination = $db->query("SELECT pk_id, project FROM dbo.destination WHERE pk_id=" . $row_rules['destination_id'] . " ORDER by project ASC");
    while($row_destination = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_destination)){
        echo "Destination project: ";
        echo "<span class='item'>".$row_destination['project']."</span>";
        echo "ID: ".$row_rules['destination_id']."<br>";
        if ($row_rules['source_id'] == null) {
            echo "Source ID for Destination ID".$row_rules['destination_id']." is NULL<br>";
        } else {
            $result_source = $db->query("SELECT pk_id, project FROM dbo.source WHERE pk_id=" . $row_rules['source_id'] . " ORDER by project ASC");
            while($row_source = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_source)){    
                echo "Source project: ";
                echo $row_source['project'];
                echo " ID: ".$row_rules['source_id']."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here's what my tables look like:

Source table: pk_id:int, project:varchar(50), feature:varchar(50), milestone:varchar(50), reviewGroup:varchar(125), groupId:int

Rules table: pk_id:int, source_id:int, destination_id:int, login:varchar(50), status:varchar(50), batchId:int, srcPGroupId:int, dstPGroupId:int

Destination table: pk_id:int, project:varchar(50), feature:varchar(50), milestone:varchar(50), QAAssignedTo:varchar(50), ValidationAssignedTo:varchar(50), Priority:varchar(50), groupId:int

Comment: How are your tables indexed?

Comment: Combine your two queries using a `JOIN`.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: You should look into using SQL joins. You are making far too many calls to the database. If you have 5 sources and 7 destinations for each then you are making 35 SELECT queries against the database. If you were using a JOIN, then you would make one SELECT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want help with optimizing queries then please provide details of the schema and the output of the explain plan.

Running nested loops is bad for performance. Running queries inside nested loops like this is a recipe for VERY poor performance. Using '*' in select is bad for performance too (particularly as your only ever using a couple of columns).

You should start by optimizing your PHP and merging the queries:

```
$result_rules = $db->query(
     "SELECT rule.destination_id, [whatever fields you need from dbo.rules] 
             dest.project AS dest_project,
             src.project AS src_project,
             src.pk_id as src_id
      FROM dbo.rules rule
      INNER JOIN dbo.destination dest
          ON dest.pk_id=rule.destination_id
      LEFT JOIN dbo.source src
          ON src.pk_id=rule.source_id
      ORDER BY rule.destination_id, dest.project, src.project");

$last_dest=false;
$last_src=false;
while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){  
    if ($row['destination_id']!==$last_dest) {
       echo "Destination project: ";
       echo "<span class='item'>".$row['dest_project']."</span>";
       echo "ID: ".$row['destination_id']."<br>";
       $last_dest=$row['destination_id'];
    }
    if (null===$row['src_id']) {
       ... I'll let you sort out the rest.
```

Comment: Just changed SELECT * to select specific columns. That was something I meant to do but forgot. I'll give the JOINs a try, definitely looks like it'll help massively. Also added information on what my tables look like.

Comment: Why do we need to check $last_dest?

Comment: Because you want to ouput your "Destination project: " header when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on `(pk_id, project)` so it includes all fields important for the query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that pk_Id is indexed: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp
2. Rather than using select *, return only the columns you need, unless you need all of them.
3. I'd also recommend moving your SQL code to the server and calling the stored procedure.
4. You could consider using LIMIT if your back end is mysql: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm .

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to the database via a read-only account. And I need to pull all the rows in those 3 tables. Is there something dumb I'm doing in my PHP logic I could possibly improve?

Comment: Step #2 you can still do, so select colA, colB, colC from table rather than select * from table.  Also, you can see what buffering does for your performance: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?471650-what-are-buffered-queries .

Comment: I just updated to select the specific columns. I'll take a look at buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the else clause is what's slowing up your code. I would suggest saving all the data you're going to need at the start and then accessing the array again in the else clause. Basically, you don't need this to run every time.

```
$result_destination = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dbo.destination WHERE pk_id=" . $row_rules['destination_id'] . " ORDER by project ASC")
```

You could grab the data earlier and use PHP to iterate over it.

```
$result_destinations = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dbo.destination ORDER by project ASC")
```

And then later in your code use PHP to determine the correct destination. Depending on exactly what you're doing it should shave some amount of time off.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you would want to lower the number of queries run. For example doing a query, looping through those results and running another query, then looping through that result set running more queries is generally considered bad. The number of queries run goes up exponentially.

For example, if you have 100 rows coming back from the first query and 10 rows from each sub-query. The first query returns 100 rows that you loop over. For each of those you query again. You are now at 101 queries. Then, for each of those 100 you run another query each returning 10 rows. You are now at 1001 queries. Each query has to send data to the server (the query text), wait for a response and get data back. That is what takes so long.

Use a join to do a single query on all the tables and loop over the single result.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is the time it takes for your browser to render the html generated by your php code.  The more data you are presenting, the longer it's going to take.  Depending on the requirements of your audience, you might want to display only x records at a time.

There are jquery methods of increasing the number of records displayed without going back to the server.